# Laravel 5.8: Migrations Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: php, laravel

I created two tables and in the second one I set up a foreign key. When I call the comand `php artisan migrate` I get following error:

> Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

The first table name is members and the second partners

```
$table->integer('member_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('member_id')->on('members')->references('id')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Comment: you need to post more detail, at least the 2 migration files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all since Laravel 5.8 all id are `bigintegers`

However since they are also unsinged you can do:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('member_id');
```

For the second line you might want to change the order:

```
$table->foreign('member_id')->references('id')->on('members')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Do note that the `members` table should be created first before you can reference a key of it.

Comment: Thank you all for your support. With  $table->unsignedBigInteger('member_id'); works.

Answer (score 1):

```
$table->integer('member_id')->unsigned();
```

change as

```
$table->bigInteger('member_id')->unsigned();
```

becouse laravel use as default bigIncrement for id columns in migration files.

Answer (score 0):

Your members table should be created before your current table
or maybe your memers `id` field has different type than your current table
please post your migration files